# does i/o operations within loop decrease performance?

Tags: performance, algorithm, io

I am confused how to take inputs from file. In many of hacking challenge sites input will be in the format

-no of test cases

case1

case2

..so on

My question is what is the best way to read the inputs. Whether i should read all the cases in one loop, store it in an array and then perform operations on the inputs in separate loop OR just use one loop for both- to read and perform operations on input. Is there any performance issue between these two methods?

Comment: What happened when you measured it?

Comment: Keep in mind, if your files are measured in KB, it probably doesn't matter. Be sure to check you actually have a performance issue before you optimize for it!

Comment: There probably isn't a big difference between the two, but most code I've seen reads the code and processes it in the same loop. And you **might** have memory issues with storing the entire file (though it's not too likely).

Answer (score 2):

There's no definite answer to your question. Basically, "it depends".

A general performance-affecting principle that should be observed in many cases on modern hardware platforms is as follows: when you attempt to do many unrealted (or loosely related) things at once, involving access to several unrelated regions of memory, the memory locality of your code worsens and the cache behavior of your program worsens as well. Bad memory locality and the consequent poor cache behavior can have notable negative impact on the performance of your code. For this reason, it is usually good idea to organize your code in consequent stages, each stage working within a more-or-less well defined localized memory region.

This is a very general principle that is not directly related to input/output. It just that input/output might prove to be one of those things that could make your code to do "too many things at once". Whether it will have an impact on the performance of your code really depends on the specifics of your code.

If your code is dominated by slow input/output operations, then its cache performance will not be a significant factor at all. If, on the other hand, your code spends most of its time doing memory-intensive computations, then it might be a good idea to experiment with such things as elimination of I/O operations from the main computation cycles.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say not significantly. Either way, the same number of operations will be performed, the question is about clumping together "the same kind" of operations. Like AndreyT said, organizing it based in stages that act on the same general area of memory might increase performance. It really depends on the kind of input and output your doing, as well as some operating system and programming language specific variables. The question basically comes down to the question of if "input output input output" is slower than "input input output output", and I think that depends highly on the programming language and the data-structures you're using. Look up how to set a timer or stopwatch on some code, and you can test it out for yourself. My hunch is that it will make very little to no difference, but you could be using different data-structures than I have in mind, so you'll just have to test it out.

So it could help, but in my experience unless you're doing some serious number crunching or need a highly optimized code, there's a certain point where gaining a fraction of a second faster operation isn't necessary. Modern computers run so blindingly fast that you usually have a lot of computational power to spare. Of course, in a case where you're doing something really computationally intensive, every little bit helps. It's all about trade-off between programming time and running time.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on some variants:

- **Type of operation ?** Input or Output
- **Parallel ?** Sync call or Async call
- **Parallelism Degree ?** is there dependency between iterations